# How to find variables for ideviceimagemounter

Tags: ios, macos, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to mount my iphone and browse its filesystem on my Mac like any other hard drive. I've got `ideviceimagemounter` installed, but I don't know how to find the variables it wants as input.

`ideviceimagemounter [OPTIONS] IMAGE_FILE IMAGE_SIGNATURE_FILE`

Neither of these fields `IMAGE_FILE` or `IMAGE_SIGNATURE_FILE` are printed by `ideviceinfo`.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using [IExplorer](https://iexplorer.en.softonic.com/)?

Comment: @tomerpacific I'm on a mac, updated the q.

Comment: You can use iExplorer for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you run "ideviceimagemounter -h" on command line, then you should be able to get the options:

Usage: ideviceimagemounter [OPTIONS] IMAGE_FILE IMAGE_SIGNATURE_FILE

Mounts the specified disk image on the device.

OPTIONS:
-u, --udid UDID   target specific device by UDID
-n, --network     connect to network device
-l, --list        List mount information
-t, --imagetype   Image type to use, default is 'Developer'
-x, --xml     Use XML output
-d, --debug       enable communication debugging
-h, --help        prints usage information
-v, --version     prints version information

Homepage:    https://libimobiledevice.org
Bug Reports: https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/issues

Comment: On a Mac, my DeveloperDiskImage is in the following directory:

ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/15.2

total 23392

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  11968751 Nov 18 23:37 DeveloperDiskImage.dmg

-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel       128 Nov 18 23:37 DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature